# How to correct display of curly braces in an input prompt?

Tags: python-3.x, input, curly-braces

I have some basic code to roll dice in python3, my input field is producing curly braces instead of an desired integer. How do I get my integer to show in place of my curly braces?

For a personal project trying to better understand python.
I haven't tried anything as I am still new to python and unsure of where to begin. Tried searching here, found things either too advanced for me to understand, or issues far more specific than I need.

```
from random import randint

def roll(sides, number):
    return [randint(1, sides) for i in range(number)]

sides = int(input("\nHow many sides do you want on your dice?:  "))
number = int(input("\nHow many {} sided dice do you want to roll?:  "))
results = roll(sides, number)

sides = int(sides)
number = int(sides)
print(results)
```

Expected result if I input 10 and 2 (as an example):
How many sides do you want on your die?: 10
How many 10 sided die do you want to roll?: 2

Output is instead:
How many sides do you want on your dice?:  10

How many {} sided dice do you want to roll?:  2

I apologize if this is a silly question, but I am unsure of where to start.

Apologies in advance if the formatting here is strange, this is my first post on here, and I am unsure of proper methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Python 3.6 or above, you can use [Formatted string literals](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#pep-498-formatted-string-literals) using the "f" prefix, like so: `f"your {var} variable"`. For instance:

```py
number = int(input(f"\nHow many {sides} sided dice do you want to roll?:  "))
```

Or, you can explicitly use the *format* method:

```py
number = int(input("\nHow many {sides} sided dice do you want to roll?:  ".format(sides=sides)))
```

or

```py
number = int(input("\nHow many {} sided dice do you want to roll?:  ".format(sides)))
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks you so much! The formatted string literals worked!

Comment: Thanks, so all you need to do is to accept this answer.

Comment: sorry, I'm new to Stack Overflow, how do I do that?
Edit: I figured it out, sorry I missed the giant check mark!